# liferay-6.1 - Implement own service

Tags: liferay-6

Hey I have create my own service.xml  with student. Now o want to add my own searchByName method for student. can you please explain me what to write in StudentLocalServiceImpl.

```
 public class StudentLocalServiceImpl extends StudentLocalServiceBaseImpl {
/*
 * NOTE FOR DEVELOPERS:
  *
 */

public List<Student> getAll() throws SystemException {
    return studentPersistence.findAll();
}

public Student getStudentByName(String name) {
    return studentPersistence.
}
```

// I have created one method getAll.
 I need help for the another one.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would first declare this as a "finder" element in the `service.xml` within the entity you defined.

e.g.

```xml
<finder name="Name" return-type="Student">
    <finder-column name="name" />
</finder>
```

The `return-type` could also be `Collection` if wanting a `List<Student>` as the return type, if name is not unique.

```xml
<finder name="Name" return-type="Collection">
    <finder-column name="name" />
</finder>
```

You can also state a comparison operator for the column:

```xml
<finder name="NotName" return-type="Collection">
    <finder-column name="name" comparator="!=" />
</finder>
```

A finder can actually declare a unique index as well to be generated on this relation (will be applied to the DB table) by specifying the `unique="true"` attribute on the finder:

```xml
<finder name="Name" return-type="Student" unique="true">
    <finder-column name="name" />
</finder>
```

With this definition and after re-runing `ant build-service` the `studentPersistence` will contain new methods using the name of the finder found in the xml element appended with a prefix: countBy, findBy, fetchBy, removeBy, etc.

Finally, your serice method would only need to contain the following (based on the above):

```java
public Student getStudentByName(String name) throws SystemException {
    return studentPersistence.findByName(name);
}
```

HTH

Comment: Thanks a lot Ray It helped me lot.. :)